# Chrome 70.x not blocking cookies

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I have Chrome Version 70.0.3538.102 (Official Build) (64-bit) installed on my machine.  In the settings I have some explicitly listed sites to block cookies from like:

- `[*.].facebook.com`
- `[*.].twitter.com`
- `[*.].salesforce.com`
- `[*.].force.com`

Whenever I go to check the cookies in the browser I still see cookies from Twitter, Facebook and a few others in there.  Anyone else having this issue or is my syntax just wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is my syntax just wrong?

You have an extra `.` in your expression:

> To create an exception for an entire domain, insert `[*.]` before the domain name. For example, `[*.]google.com` will match `drive.google.com` and `calendar.google.com`.

Source [Clear, enable and manage cookies in Chrome - Computer - Google Chrome Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en-GB)

Comment: AH HA!  it *WAS* my syntax.  I knew something was screwy.  Thank you!